# Property "Value" is already defined. How resolve from ANT

Tags: jaxb, conflict

I am using ANT build.xml to generate java proxy class. There i am getting below error.

**"[wsimport] [ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict."**

How to perform external binding through ANT build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [xjc ANT task](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/xjcTask.html)
- write a bindings (.xjb) to define the appropriate `jaxb:property`
- add -b argument to xjc execution task in ANT.

> ```
> <arg value="-b"/>
> <arg value="bindings.xjb"/>
> ```